# "Carry on" vs "carry on with"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Does the insertion of *with* here make a difference? Is one incorrect, or one more correct than the other?

- to carry on watching the cartoon
- to carry on with watching the cartoon

Comment: The first sounds more natural and avoids unwanted connotations (carrying on *with* someone *could* imply having an affair for example)... though nobody like cartoons *that* much (Jessica Rabbit notwithstanding perhaps) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible as there's no difference  in meaning.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***carry on with***

idiom

to continue doing or participating in (an activity)

// They carried on with their conversation

***carry on***

transitive verb

to continue doing, pursuing, or operating

// carry on research
// carried on the business

Comment: I think the note '(an activity)' is significant. You carry on doing something, but carry on _with_ a task, conversation etc.